# Super Key (Windows key) occasionally gets "stuck" until logout

Tags: keyboard

I've updated from 18.10 to 19.04. But the whenever I press the super key (windows key), the keyboard occasionally gets "stuck" until logout. whats  this?

Comment: Clarify what you mean with "stuck".

Comment: Same here. Press Super Key and the (probably) window manager does not allow interaction with any other window. Top right menu works for logging out and resetting the behavior. I disabled gnome extensions and seems to work again.

Comment: I mean my laptop's keyboard doesn't works after pressing the super key..

Comment: I managed to fix it after removing 'Workspace Grid' GNOME extension.